# Delete ActiveMQ subscribers

Tags: activemq-classic, jms-topic, subscriber

I am trying to reset ActiveMQ by deleting all subscribers and topics. I know that I can delete  subscribers/topics by clicking delete link in the Web UI. Is there a way to delete them all at once?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you wanting to use the web console to delete them all at once or some other method (e.g. programmatic)?

Comment: Web console would be preferable. If not, a programatical approach  is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration did what I wanted to do.
**deleteAllMessagesOnStartup="true"**

Comment: If this is the right answer please mark it as correct to make it more clear to other users who may have this same question in the future. Thanks!